# Using Mysqli bind_param with date and time columns?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do you insert data into a MySQL date or time column using PHP mysqli and bind_param?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Like any other string

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('insert into foo (dt) values (?)');
$dt = '2009-04-30 10:09:00';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $dt);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 16):

Timestamps in PHP are integers (the number of seconds from the UNIX epoch). An alternative to the above is to use an integer type date/time parameter, and the MySQL functions `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO FOO (dateColumn) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(?))");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $your_date_parameter);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @Rob: When I use this, the date set is 1970/01/01

Comment: The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

Answer (score 2):

For the current date/time you can use the MySQL standard routine. You do not have to prepare that.

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO tablename ";
$query .= "VALUES(?,?,?,NOW()) ";
$preparedquery = $dbaselink->prepare($query);
$preparedquery->bind_param("iii",$val1,$val2,$val3);
```

Answer (score -1):

first set the date & time using date() function-

```
$date=date("d/m/y");
$time=date("h:i:sa");
```

then pass it into the prepared statement, just like any other string variable-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO FOO (dateColumn, timeColumn) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $date , $time);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It is not working for me I get the error: `[Fatal error] Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` I'm doing the same but I get this error.