# MySQL bind_param and date stored as integer (produced by java)

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I have timestamp `Thu, 07 May 2015 16:52:43 GMT` stored like this:

```
$timestamp = 1431017563117;
```

Variable with this value was produced by Java (Location.getTime() method from Android SDK).

I'm trying to store it in database, with `mysqli->bind_param();` method. My field has `TIMESTAMP` type.

I have tried this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('di', $timestamp, $Id);
```

And this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $timestamp, $Id);
```

It just doesn't work, and MySQLi error gives me nonsense message like this:

> Creating default object from empty value in server.php on line 118

How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here: [Using Mysqli bind_param with date and time columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805828/using-mysqli-bind-param-with-date-and-time-columns)

It should be like this:

```
$java_integer_timestamp = 1431017563117;

$unix_timestamp = $java_integer_timestamp / 1000;

$query = "update Table SET DateTimeColumn = FROM_UNIXTIME(?) WHERE Id=?";

// ... prepare statement here

$stmt->bind_param('di', $unix_timestamp, $Id);
```